# Cannot create AVD via Android Studio - VT-x or SVM issue

Tags: android-studio, virtual-machine, apk, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I've recently installed Android Studio Flamingo on a Debian based distribution for reverse engineering purposes. However, when I attempt to boot up a mock device through AVD it gave me back a dialog box outlining "Your CPU does not support the required features vT-x or SVM". I find this issue quite obscure as I'm able to use a VM in the first place. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euXEt.png)

Overview of CPU:

11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 2.80G
x64-based processor

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/208921/intel-core-i71165g7-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz-with-ipu.html

Attempted Fixes:

I don't really understand why this issue is occurring in the first place.

1. My attempted fixes so far is ensuring virtualization through my BIOS or UEFI is enabled which was already enabled by default.
2. The second attempted fix was going on to my "turn windows features
   on and off" and ensuring both the virtual machine platform and the
   hypervisor platform was enabled but none of this works.
3. Further to this, I've also enabled the extended features in
   Oracle VirtualBox v 7.0 on the Debian based VM which is the Enabled Nested VT-
   x/AMD-V. I'm out of ideas, not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: Virtualbox runs fine without hypervisor of Windows, the possibility to use hypervisor is pretty new may be this is your problem. In general my feeling is that the old way works much more stable than the new hypervisor based emulation.

Comment: Are you suggesting to turn off hypervisor and check if I can boot up an AVD via studio

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggest.

Comment: I've just turned it off via Turn Windows on and off features and booted up the VM, launched up studio alongside the AVD Nexus 5, the issue still persists which outlines "your CPU does not support the required features vT-x or SVM" :( I have no clue, it works on my Windows.